# Django 'logout' TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: django-views, python-3.7, django-authentication, django-class-based-views, django-3.0

Good Day,

I have a problem with authentication in Django 3.0.

My project depending on giving points for users for every action (like post, comment, like, favorite, ....).

I am using custom context_processors to get these values in multiple templates.

**My problem :** when i am logged in .. everything works fine (admin panel, new post, new comment, ....).

when i logged out .. all project get mad and all pages doesn't work .. getting the following error:

```
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='commenter')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment')
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} Commented On {}.'.format(self.user, self.post)
```

**Views.py**

```
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'user/logout.html', {})
```

**context_processors.py**

```
def extra_cp(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    postsperuser = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    postsperusercount = Post.objects.all().annotate(posts_count=Count('title')).filter(author=request.user)
    postspoints = postsperusercount.aggregate(posts_score=Count('posts_count') * 1000)

    commentsperuser = Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    commentsperusercount = Comment.objects.all().annotate(comments_count=Count('content')).filter(user=request.user)
    commentspoints = commentsperusercount.aggregate(comments_score=Count('comments_count') * 350)

    total_points = postspoints['posts_score'] + commentspoints['comments_score']

    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'postsperuser': postsperuser,
        'postspoints':postspoints,
        'commentsperuser':commentsperuser,
        'commentspoints':commentspoints,
        'comment_list': comment_list,
        'total_points': total_points,
                    }
    return context
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/', ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'common.context_processors.extra_cp'

            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Traceback Error:**

```
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'my_blog.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\src\blog-django-ar-master\src\blog\views.py", line 59, in HomePageView
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {})
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "C:\Users\clt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 246, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\src\blog-django-ar-master\src\common\context_processors.py", line 19, in extra_cp
    postsperuser = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1284, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1124, in check_related_objects
    for v in value:
  File "D:\Private\PythonProjects\ProCoers02\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
[02/Apr/2020 00:23:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 137245
```

I believe that the solution is in django sessions .. i tried several times and searched here for multiple uestions and answers, but i got failed.

Can anybody help ?

Thanks in-advance for your kind support....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after a simple modifications:

1. define user as `user.request.is_authenticated`.
2. added context as empty dictionary before if statement.
3. use if statement as shown below.
4. move context inside if statement.
5. keep return context as it is.

**context_processors.py**

```
def extra_cp(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    user = request.user.is_authenticated
    context = {}

    if user:
        postsperuser = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
        postsperusercount = Post.objects.all().annotate(posts_count=Count('title')).filter(author=request.user)
        postspoints = postsperusercount.aggregate(posts_score=Count('posts_count') * 1000)

        commentsperuser = Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        commentsperusercount = Comment.objects.all().annotate(comments_count=Count('content')).filter(user=request.user)
        commentspoints = commentsperusercount.aggregate(comments_score=Count('comments_count') * 350)

        total_points = postspoints['posts_score'] + commentspoints['comments_score']

        comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        context = {
            'categories': categories,
            'postsperuser': postsperuser,
            'postspoints': postspoints,
            'commentsperuser': commentsperuser,
            'commentspoints': commentspoints,
            'comment_list': comment_list,
            'total_points': total_points,
        }

    return context
```

**Please note:**

@Omonbude Emmanuel was true .. it must be `request.user.is_authenticated()` because of using Django 3.0.

but it worked with `request.user.is_authenticated` without `()` .. and i don't know why ......

Great thanks for you all,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering users in your context processor.
It'll only work when users are logged in.
You can use if statement to check if they're logged in or use  try and except.

Comment: thanks for your fast response, i used `if request.user.is_authenticated` and also tried try and except .. but it get nothing .. if you can give an example .. it will help alot.

Comment: What Django version are you using?If you are using Django 1.10+, then you should use the property request.user.is_authenticated.

If you are using Django 1.9 or earlier, then you must use request.user.is_authenticated().

Comment: @OmonbudeEmmanuel Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow ... Please keep in mind, that this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).